# Modifying Configuration Files in Docker Images - Node.js Configuration (app.js)

Tags: node.js, docker

This question applies to pretty much any published docker image, but in my case, I'm trying to run this docker container:  https://github.com/illuspas/Node-Media-Server/

The page linked above has a docker command.  That's great!  I can run the docker image, but it's useless unless I can change the configuration to meet my needs.  Unfortunately, that github repo doesn't seem to include any further instructions when using his app via docker.

Docker confuses me to no end.  Someone creates a pre-configured container with Node.js, so how do I edit the Node.js configuration files (app.js) that are mentioned on that GitHub page?  I want these changes to persist as well (when the server reboots).

Do I have to create my own copy of the docker container?  Do I need a docker account to commit my changes?  What's the best way to go about this, and does someone have a link to a guide that could help?  If I do make my own docker image, can I publish it somewhere for free?  Hence, then I could run my container using myusername rather than the original author's?  What about when his package gets updated?  How would I get those changes into my docker image?

Why is this so complicated?  Why wouldn't the configuration file that needs to be tweaked per running instance be stored on the real file system somewhere so that it could be easily accessed and edited?

I really don't get why docker is so popular, as it's super confusing to interact with running containers, and changing the configuration or files within a container of an existing image doesn't appear to be straightforward.

If someone could help clarify what needs to be done, I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest is to clone the repo change app.js and run `docker build` this will create a new image that you can then docker run.

You can also get a shell on an already running container using `docker exec -it $container bash` , edit the file and then do a `docker commit $container $some_name`.

I am not a big fan of option 2, but used it in the past for quick and dirty hacks.

You do not need a docker account if you just want to keep your changes private.